# Migrating uploaded files from Active Storage to Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rails-activestorage

For a variety of reasons I am migrating my uploads from ActiveStorage (AS) to CarrierWave (CW).

I am making rake task and have the logic sorted out - I am stumped at how to feed the AS blob into the CW file.

I am trying something like ths:

```
@files.each.with_index(1) do | a, index |

  if a.attachment.attached?

    a.attachment.download do |file|
      a.file = file
    end
    a.save!

  end

end
```

This is based on these two links:

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#downloading-files

```
message.video.open do |file|
  system '/path/to/virus/scanner', file.path
  # ...
end
```

and

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#activerecord

```
# like this
File.open('somewhere') do |f|
  u.avatar = f
end
```

I tested this locally and the files are not mounted via the uploader.  My question(s) would be:

- am I missing something obvious here?
- is my approach wrong and needs a new one?

Bonus Karma Question:

- I can't seem to see a clear path to set the CW filename when I do this?

Comment: I think you need to provide an object on which `.read` can be called, and the `file` object you have is a string. Can you try again, replacing `a.file = file` with `a.file = StringIO.new(file)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file` object you get from the `attachment.download` block is a string. More precisely, the response from `.download` is the file, "streamed and yielded in chunks" (see [documentation](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-download)). I validated this by calling `file.class` to make sure the class is what I expected.

So, to solve your issue, you need to provide an object on which `.read` can be called. Commonly that is done using the Ruby [StringIO](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) class.

However, considering [Carrierwave also expects a filename](https://makandracards.com/makandra/50526-fileio-writing-strings-as-carrierwave-uploads), you can solve it using a helper model that inherits `StringIO` (from blogpost linked above):

```
class FileIO < StringIO
  def initialize(stream, filename)
    super(stream)
    @original_filename = filename
  end

  attr_reader :original_filename
end
```

And then you can replace `a.file = file` with `a.file = FileIO.new(file, 'new_filename')`

Comment: I will try this tonight when I get home. 

Comment: Perfect - will post my final rake task for posterity - someone else will want to do the same thing someday.

Comment: Hmmm... it did work in Development but fails in production with a bunch of carrierwave Fog errors which is weird because I am not using Fog at all in my app.  I am using the AWS SDK gem and Digital Ocean for storage.

Comment: If you manually attach files in production, does the storage work? It sounds like configuration to me

Comment: ‍♂️ yup operator error lol.  I still has the aws gem for active storage but forgot to fully configure for CW which needed fog.  I did have fog specified by mistake also.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my final rack task (based on the accepted answer) - open to tweaks.  Does the job for me:

```
namespace :carrierwave do
  desc "Import the old AS files into CW"
  task import: :environment do

    @files = Attachment.all

    puts "#{@files.count} files to be processed"
    puts "+" * 50

    @files.each.with_index(1) do | a, index |

      if a.attachment.attached?

        puts "Attachment #{index}:  Key: #{a.attachment.blob.key} ID: #{a.id} Filename: #{a.attachment.blob.filename}"

        class FileIO < StringIO
          def initialize(stream, filename)
            super(stream)
            @original_filename = filename
          end

          attr_reader :original_filename
        end

        a.attachment.download do |file|
           a.file = FileIO.new(file, a.attachment.blob.filename.to_s)
        end
        a.save!
        puts "-" * 50

      end

    end

  end

  desc "Purge the old AS files"
  task purge: :environment do

    @files = Attachment.all

    puts "#{@files.count} files to be processed"
    puts "+" * 50


    @files.each.with_index(1) do | a, index |

      if a.attachment.attached?

        puts "Attachment #{index}:  Key: #{a.attachment.blob.key} ID: #{a.id} Filename: #{a.attachment.blob.filename}"
        a.attachment.purge
        puts "-" * 50
        @count = index

      end

    end

    puts "#{@count} files purged"


  end

end
```

Now in my case I am doing this in steps - I have branched my master with this rake task and the associated MCV updates.  If my site was in true production would probably run the import rake task first then confirm all went well THEN purge the old AS files.